# Cannot get external data during DoEvents

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA sub in Excel that executes DoEvents until the requirements are met.  During this loop, I need to get external data & import that data as a table into the active worksheet.   I cannot click "Existing connections" when the VBA code is in this section, and I don't understand why I can't do this.  Can anyone explain to me why this isn't possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DoEvents` allows *other* applications time to run and prevents your VBA code from locking the entire system. It does *not* allow you to interact with the VBA host application (Excel in this case), because the VBA code is currently executing.

From the [MS documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/118468):

> The DoEvents function surrenders execution of the macro so that the operating system can process other events. The DoEvents function **passes control from the application to the operating system**. Some instances in which DoEvents may be useful include the following:
>
> - Hardware I/O
> - Delay Loops
> - Operating System Calls
> - DDE Deadlocking

<sup>**Emphasis** mine</sup>

You may want to investigate integrating the 'get external data & import' process into your VBA code. It would, however, have to happen either *before* or *after* the `DoEvents` loop, not during.